# Davening in "night clothes"

Tags: halacha, clothing, sleep

The lockdowns and subsequent increase in work-from-home families has created a new set of circumstances worth thinking about.

[It is against halacha to daven in a "sleeping robe" שלאף ראק](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.91.11?lang=bi&with=Halakhah%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en). Nowadays, it's not uncommon for people to wear "comfortable" clothes while at home. They will not necessarily (hopefully!) be the same clothes they slept in the night before, but they are likely to be the same ones they *plan* to sleep in the coming night.

Does this simple fact alone count them as "night clothes" or does the fact they *are* being worn during the day for work count them as non-night clothes for davening purposes?

I am considering this person might daven from home, or even daven in a minyan having thrown on a quick shirt and/or trousers over them (depending on how "smart" they are). I personally have some very smart looking "comfortable" trousers that could pass in public as normal looking, smart trousers, but I do sleep in them.

Comment: It seems to me that the MB's problem is that such robes don't have a trouser part, which pyjamas definitely have. See https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.6.3 https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.23

Comment: @Kazibácsi Not sure as he's also talking about undergarments, which could have "trouser parts" (long johns etc). Please check this question again in a day or so, I've definitely seen sources that paint the problem as one of kavod for Hashem

Comment: Again, in the MB _kaftan_ and _schlafrock_ are mentioned, both are trouserless robes, while undergarments are definitely not pyjamas. Peninei Halakhah mentions what you say, but I'm not perfectly sure that I understand how does he arrive to that conclusion.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I am frustrated because yesterday I saw it in another good place, I think Yalkut Yosef, but can't find it! I think my 2 year old just handed it to me and I opened a random page. The context was kavod Hashem. I thought this would be very easy to look up, didn't expect this much resistance to the question :)

Comment: @Kazibácsi btw, is _schlafrock_ well known to be a trouserless robe in yiddish or do you know this from some other source? Still haven't come across my mysterious "source" but keeping an eye open

Comment: Schlaf = sleep, Rock = robe, skirt. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schlafrock

Comment: @Kazibácsi thanks for helping this clueless sefardi