Standards of a Place for Davening
Is a Jew allowed to daven in bed? Can one daven in their pajamas in a place? Can a Jew daven in the same room as an unmade bed?
PS: This question is alluding to ALL contexts (i.e. whether is person is sick, healthy, in a dorm, at home, etc.).

Go visit any bedridden person - or a hospital - and it's clear that all the above is OK for patients. Are you maybe asking about lazy healthy people? ("Context" may currently be a non-PC word, but your Q needs some.)

In the title of your question you ask about a proper place, while in the question you ask about clothing as well. These are two different things, please make clear what you're interested in.

Regarding proper clothes see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28555/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132247/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70040/15256

Dressing appropriately depends on the current trends and the setting, as well as how people behave in public and around important figures. If short sleeve shirts or sandals without socks are acceptable, there is usually no need to change for prayer. However, it is important to wear respectable clothing when standing before Hashem.
Piskei Teshuvot
There are significantly different halachos if a person is bedridden due to illness, c”v, as opposed to healthy. If a person is sick, CYLOR.

In the Mesoras Moshe, Rabbi Moshe Feinstein's secretary quotes something similar from when Rabbi Feinstein was hospitalized: if someone's healthy and up and about, and chooses to pray in pajamas, we would ask "is that how you would dress to meet the President?" But if someone's hospitalized, we ask: "suppose the President was touring the hospital and came to your room" -- basically you'd make sure your pajamas and/or gown were decent, and that's about it.
